# Mac OS classic: cannot open resolver

Tags: mac-os-classic

A new, exciting error on macOS 7.5.5 — my fresh install of Open Transport 1.3 delivered working connectivity, but after a crash an error “cannot open resolver” has been persistently in the way of TCP/IP connections.

[image]

This came about after an improper shutdown. I have been unable to figure out what component provides DNS resolution and how to restore it without a reinstall. Suggestions are very appreciated, as I cannot seem to find the exact error message on the interwebs.

Comment: Have not seen that one before. If a reinstall of just OpenTransport can fix it, then I would chalk it up as a lesson in OpenTransport's reliability.

Comment: OT reinstall did not fix it. I had to restore N older copy of the OS from backups and work back from there.

Comment: I feel like I concluded a long time ago that MacTCP was better for 68K machines. Can't really remember how I arrived at that conclusion, though.

Comment: @BrianH i sort of make the same assumption, but there is a modern SSH client for 68k, and it requires OT.